# ASP.NET pass model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class like so:

```
public class wsvListTagHistoryClass
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string Entered { get; set; }
        public string DHours { get; set; }
        public string GPS { get; set; }
    }
```

and in my View Controller, I am populating the class like so:

```
int TagId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TagId"]);

            wsvListTagHistoryCell = new List<wsvListTagHistoryClass>();

            try
            {
                //Create SQL Connection

                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {

                    //Open Connection

                    connection.Open();

                    //Run iosShowGroup Stored Procedure

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("wsvListTagHistory", connection))
                    {

                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Input Parameters

                        SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@TagId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        parameter1.Value = TagId;
                        parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);

                        //Execute Query

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            //Get Group Data

                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                //Create New Class Object

                                wsvListTagHistoryClass item = new wsvListTagHistoryClass();

                                //Populate Object with Results

                                item.TagId = (int)reader[0];
                                item.GroupId = (int)reader[1];
                                item.GroupName = reader[2].ToString();
                                item.Entered = reader[3].ToString();
                                item.DHours = reader[4].ToString();
                                item.GPS = reader[5].ToString();

                                //Add Results to List

                                wsvListTagHistoryCell.Add(item);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //Close Connection

                connection.Close();
            }

            return View(wsvListTagHistoryCell.ToList());
```

and then trying to do a foreach in my view like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebServiceAPI.Models.wsvListTagHistoryClass>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TagId )
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

I get no errors, but my problem is that nothing appears, the TagId does not appear at all. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: better try exec your storeprod in SQL management studio etc to check whether it has output (TagId)

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the return view line to see if you're actually returning anything, and if you are, set a breakpoint on the @foreach in the view to see what it is doing. 

Once you have it working, move that Sql functionality to another class, keeping your controller lean and clean is a good practice.

Comment: Might be a typo in the foreach on the View, but why is it modelItem => item.TagId? Shouldn't it be modelItem => modelItem.TagId?

Comment: Do you check the `wsvListTagHistoryCell.Count` before returning? Is it not empty

Comment: wsvListTagHistoryClass needs an empty constructor

Comment: @Markus because he uses `item` in the `Model` -> it should be fine

Comment: Have you verified that wsvListTagHistoryCell is not empty?

Comment: it is 100% not empty

Comment: Have you tried using `catch` to identify any errors? Your piece of code does not have one. Could be that your list is empty because of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the object with data.

```
    wsvListTagHistoryClass item = new wsvListTagHistoryClass();
    item.TagId = (int)reader[0];
    item.GroupId = (int)reader[1];
    item.GroupName = reader[2].ToString();
    item.Entered = reader[3].ToString();
    item.DHours = reader[4].ToString();
    item.GPS = reader[5].ToString();
    return View(item);
```

remove `wsvListTagHistoryCell.Add(item);`
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the use of `DisplayFor`. This method extends an `HtmlHelper` class. Each view has an `HtmlHelper` for the model type that is defined at the top. Though your code compiles, by using

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TagId);
```

you tell the View to create a display for the property `TagId` on the model which is of type `IEnumerable<WebServiceAPI.Models.wsvListTagHistoryClass>`. Though the lambda expression does not lead to a property on the model (remember, the `HtmlHelper` is strongly typed for the model type `IEnumerable<WebServiceAPI.Models.wsvListTagHistoryClass>`), MVC is "nice" enough to not raise an error but to simple not render anything.

In order to solve this I can recommend the following options:

Instead of iterating the items in the model in a `foreach`, just use `Html.DisplayFor(x => x)` without a `foreach` clause. MVC will iterate the items and try to display them. In order to just show the `TagId` property, you could create a **display template** for your model class. See this [link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) for an overview of Display and Editor templates.

If there is no display layout that can be used generally for displaying `wsvListTagHistoryClass` you can also create a **Partial** for the model type `wsvListTagHistoryClass`. You keep your `foreach` statement and render the Partial for each item:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("PartialTestModel", item);
}
```

The Partial code is similar to the following:

```
@model TestWebAppMVC.Models.TestModel
<div>
    Tag ID = @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TagId)
</div>
```